# Hibernate Search criteria by two diffent column concatenation?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE CONCAT( first_name, ', ', last_name ) LIKE '%Dineshkumar, gaj%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Like this query how to create a search criteria in hibernate. This query searches using `firstname`, `lastname`.

Comment: What is your exact question. Please elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `concat` in `where` clause is possible in `criteria` API.

But you can use `HQL` for the same. Try the following code:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from User where firstName || lastName like ?");
q.setParameter(0, "%Dineshkumar, gaj%");
q.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(30);
List users = q.list();
```